# Why I am getting segmentation fault when trying to run the find function even though accessing memory properly?

Tags: c, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior

Find function is not working in the program.
I think it is because of segmentation fault as my compiler is showing, but I am not able to understand why? Because I used memory properly.
If it is not because of segmentation fault, then why I am not getting my desired output, even though I am not getting any error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find(int **p) {
    int small,large,i,j;
    small=large=p[i][j];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            if(small>p[i][j])
                small=p[i][j];
            else if(large<p[i][j])
                large=p[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("\nSmallest : %d\nLargest : %d",small,large);
}

int main() {
    int **p;
    p=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    if(p==NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        *(p+i)=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    }
    int j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
            scanf("%d",(*(p+i)+j));
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
            printf("\nValue of [%d][%d] : %d",i,j,*(*(p+i)+j));
    }
    find(p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `small=large=p[i][j];` this line seems to be an issue. Try initializing i and j to 0.

Comment: Your compiler indicates a segfault? I do not get that. Can you elaborate? Please describe the symptoms you get (with defined input to reproduce them).

Comment: Indeed, `small=large=p[i][j];` without `i` and `j` initialized is undefined behaviour, so the compiler may do anything; segfault is a relatively sane result, at that

Comment: Unrelated: ".... even though accessing memory properly?" You don't get a segmentation fault when doing things **properly**. A segmentation fault is always because you are doing something wrong....

Comment: Unrelated: A compiler doesn't show nor give a segmentation fault. Segmentation faults can come when you execute/run the program but not during compilation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You know, that you can write this monster `*(*(p+i)+j))` way more readable as `p[i][j]`, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo

```
p=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
                        ^^^
```

It seems you mean

```
p=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*3);
                        ^^^^^
```

Apart from this memory freeing

```
free(p);
```

you need also to free each allocated array as for example

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    free( *( p + i ) );
}

free( p );
```

Within the function `find` you are using uninitialized variables `i` and `j`.

```
void find(int **p) {
    int small,large,i,j;
    small=large=p[i][j];
    //...
```

You need to initialize them

```
void find(int **p) {
    int small,large,i = 0,j = 0;
    small=large=p[i][j];
    //...
```

Though it would be simpler to write at least like

```
void find(int **p) {
    int small = p[0][0], large = p[0][0];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    //...
```